# Unable to access “319 GB Volume”. Windows didn't shut down properly

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-10

I am absolutely brand new to Ubuntu, having tried it a few years ago and didn't continue with it because my often used software would not work on it.

I still need to use Windows from time to time and I have a dual boot system on a Dell Inspiron n5010 laptop.  This morning when using Windows, Skype tried and failed to update.  I shut down restarted and booted to Ubuntu.  Trying to access the files in the windows partition gave this message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/nick/426268B36268AD7B: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda3" "/media/nick/426268B36268AD7B"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I shutdown Widows fully but still get the same error.  At this stage I don't know enough to or *mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option*.

Since posting this question I have found that restarting rather than shutting down after using windows cured the problem.  I have no hibernate option in my windows 10

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda3 /media/nick/426268B36268AD7B
```

If it does not work try:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3
```

Then try to mount again

You may need to install some of these components like:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

This could be risky but usually goes well.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question.  I had been shutting down my computer between sessions.  It seems that restarting instead of shutting down after windows made the difference.